# Why is type inference for an inline function forcing an argument to be of a certain type, as opposed to restricting it to having op_Explicit?

Tags: generics, f#, constraints, type-inference

A very handy feature in F# is that you can do inlining and keep a certain level of value type polymorphism (though I believe "duck-typing" is more appropriate):

```
// can be used with any argument that implements op_Explicit: ^a -> float
let inline Divide a b = float a / float b
```

But when I expand it to be contained within a certain type, F# infers the first argument to be of `float`, even though I explicitly ask for *conversion to float*. What am I missing, or better yet, how can I get the `op_Explicit` behavior back? I tried adding static member constraints, but that didn't seem to help:

```
type XTest<'T> =
    | Value of 'T
    | Other of 'T 
    // a is inferred as float, b as req. op_Explicit
    static member inline Divide a b =
        match a with
        | Value x -> 
            match b with
            | Value y ->
                let res = float x / float y
                XTest.Value res |> Some
            | _ -> failwith "not implemented"

        | Other x-> Some (XTest.Other x)
```

Perhaps important to note: if I remove the `Other` discriminated union, it infers the type of the first argument properly as *"requires member op_Explicit"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not because of type inference failure. In fact, if you look closer, you'll see that `y` is correctly inferred to be `'a (requires op_Explicit)`.

Since the "failure" only applies to `x`, but not to `y`, let's see: how is `x` different from `y`?

The answer is on the last line: `x` is used to construct an instance of `XTest<'T>`. But what is `T`? Well, obviously, `'T` is the generic argument of the `Divide`'s return type, but what is that return type?

The answer to *that* is on the fourth line from the bottom: `XTest.Value res`. Since `res` is a `float` (result of dividing two `float`s), this means that `Divide`'s return type must be `XTest<float> option`, which in turn means that the last line must also produce `XTest<float>`, which means that `x` must be `float`.

A triumph of type inference. Not a failure. :-)

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer, as always :). It implicitly shows the solution, too. I just needed to let type inference know that `x` is not known to be of type `float`, which I did by changing the last line to `Some (XTest.Other (float x))`.